# Find 2 unit vectors that make an angle of $60^\text{o}$ with $\vec v=\langle 3,4 \rangle$

Tags: vector-spaces

> Find 2 unit vectors that make an angle of $60^\text{o}$ with $\vec v=\langle 3,4 \rangle$.

My working:

$$\cos{60^\text{o}}=\frac{1}{2}= \frac{\langle u_1,u_2\rangle\cdot\langle 3,4\rangle}{5\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}}=\frac{3u_1+4u_2}{5\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}}$$

Now, $u_1^2+u_2^2=1\quad\Rightarrow u_1=\pm\sqrt{1-u_2^2}$

So, $$\frac{5}{2}=\pm3\sqrt{1-u_2^2}+4u_2\\\text{ }\\
36(1-u_2^2)=25-80u_2+64u_2^2\\\text{ }\\
100u_2^2-80u_2-11=0\\\text{ }\\
u_2=\frac{4\pm3\sqrt{3}}{10}\approx-0.120 \quad \text{or}\quad 0.920\\\text{ }\\
\therefore u_1\approx -0.393 \quad \text{or} \quad 0.993\\
\text{ }\\
\text{i.e. the solutions are}\quad \langle-0.393,0.920\rangle \text{   and   } \langle0.993, -0.120\rangle$$
Are my solutions correct?

(Stewart: Calculus and Concepts, Section 9.3 no. 26)

Comment: Nice handwriting, but I preferred if you include a text version.

Answer (score 1):

What if you get the angle of that vector i.e., $\theta=arctan \dfrac{4}{3}$? Then, as now you know the angle, make $\theta+60^o=\gamma$ , and consider $v_1=(cos\gamma, sen\gamma)$. Centainly that vector makes an angle of $60^o$ with the given one and certainly it's magnitude is 1.

Make an analogous process for $-60^o$

Comment: Good. Thank you. I suggest you use a ``\`` before your trig functions so that they don't come up as italics.