# Find two vectors that make an angle of $60^\text{o}$ with $\vec v= \langle 3,4 \rangle$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

[I'm possibly going against the site's etiquette by doing this, but I'm aware that this question has already been asked- the reason I'm posting this new one is that (1) it seems that the original question didn't get much attention, and (2) I have my own specific confusion related to this question, which may fall outside the scope of what the original question was asking. Additionally, (3) I was hesitant to post a bounty mostly because of reason (2), and the fact that I don't have much reputation to give. Feel free to merge if necessary, after this question has some answers on it. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks!]

[Find 2 unit vectors that make an angle of $60^\text{o}$ with $\vec v=\langle 3,4 \rangle$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944359/find-2-unit-vectors-that-make-an-angle-of-60-texto-with-vec-v-langle-3-4)

My question is: At the end of the asker's solution, wouldn't there actually be four values for $u_1$ that come from $u_2$, since there are two values for $u_2$ and two values of $u_1$ corresponding to each $u_2$? Is this a problem? If not, how do we know which $u_1$ to pick? Also, if the asker's solution is incorrect, can someone explain why, and then post a correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should recheck your answer by getting 4 values .Also, it is clearly visible that if you take ⟨−0.393,-0.920⟩ , dot product will be negative and if you take <0.993,0.120> ,dot product will be more than 2.5 (as .9*3 = 2.7).That's why these are not included in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

let $t = \cos^{-1}\frac 3 5$ so that $$v=(3, 4) = 5(\cos t, \sin t).$$ now the two vectors at $60^\circ$ to $v$ are $$5(\cos(t\pm 60^\circ), \sin(t\pm 60^\circ)=5\left(\frac35 \frac 12\mp\frac45\frac{\sqrt3}2, \frac45 \frac 12\pm\frac35\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)=\frac 12\left(3\mp4\sqrt3,4\pm3\sqrt3\right) $$